# How to create an image out of a custom control in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a custom control in my app that works very well. Now i want to make an image out of that view.

My custom control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Project.Controls"
     xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
     xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"
     xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
     x:Name="ParentView"
     x:Class="Project.Controls.CustomControl">


     <Label x:Name = "myLabelInMyXaml" BackgroundColor = "{Binding CustomColorViewModel}"/>
```

And it's code behind:

```
public partial class CustomControl : Grid
{
   public static readonly BindableProperty ItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Item), typeof(Item), typeof(CustomGrid), propertyChanged: ItemChanged);
public static readonly BindableProperty CustomColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsAnonymousSubColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomGrid), propertyChanged: CustomColorChanged);

public Color CustomColor
{
    get { return (Color)GetValue(CustomColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CustomColorProperty, value); }
}

static void CustomColorChanged (object bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var x = bindable as CustomGrid;

    if (x.Item != null)
    {
         x.myLabelInMyXaml.BackgroundColor = x.CustomColor;
    }
}

static void ItemChanged (object bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var x = bindable as CustomGrid;
}

public Item Item
{
    get { return (Item) GetValue(ItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
}

public CustomGrid()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

}

So this code works fine and shows up fine in the app. Now i have prepared a button to share this through the Xamarin.Essentials plugin. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
     Title = Title,
     File = new ShareFile("" /* this is where the image will go*/)
});
```

Now my question is, how can i turn this custom control, into an imagesource? the part after where i turn it into a HTTP address is already something that i've prepared. so to clarify; the question is regarding how to turn a custom control into a imagesource/byte[].

Comment: @Jason, what u linked takes a screenshot of the whole phone. I am asking to take a screenshot / create an image of 1 particular control.

Comment: the basic principle is the same, just modify to use a specific view instead of the entire screen

Comment: yeah well noted. so i need to convert a xamarin forms view to a UIView by the looks of it.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/131648/how-to-generate-an-image-from-a-stacklayout

Comment: https://michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/ found a good example here, but i am unsure what to send in as GCRect size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412402/how-to-convert-xamarin-forms-view-to-a-native-view-ios-android-with-the-same-siz