# How to convert Xamarin Forms view to a Native view iOS/Android with the same size?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using the example here, but I am struggeling to fill in the right size parameter here so that it represents the same size as the forms view.
https://michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/

```
    public static UIView ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, CGRect size)
    {
        var renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer(view);

        renderer.NativeView.Frame = size;

        renderer.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
        renderer.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

        renderer.Element.Layout(size.ToRectangle());

        var nativeView = renderer.NativeView;

        nativeView.SetNeedsLayout();

        return nativeView;
    }
```

And for Android:

```
public static ViewGroup ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, Rectangle size)
{
    var vRenderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer (view);
    var viewGroup = vRenderer.ViewGroup;
    vRenderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout ();
    var layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams ((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
    viewGroup.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
    view.Layout (size);
    viewGroup.Layout (0, 0, (int)view.WidthRequest, (int)view.HeightRequest);
    return viewGroup; 
}
```

}

What values from my Xamarin Forms should be put in, so that it will represent the CGRect required to have the same on the Native View.

Comment: have you tried just using the width and height of the View?

Comment: it wants it in a CGRect format, where as Width & Height form Xamarin Forms are in double format. (on iOS in this case)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/coregraphics.cgrect?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#constructors

Comment: tried to make it work following the guide, but image does not take the right ratio as the control

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: got it working, had a typo.

finished code:
     var rect = new CGRect();
            rect.X = (nfloat)view.X;
            rect.Y = (nfloat)view.Y;
            rect.Width = (nfloat)view.Width;
            rect.Height = (nfloat)view.Height;

Comment: @DiddanDo If solved that , remember to update in answer when you have time . Then other people will know how to solve that :-)

Comment: yep just did! thx

Answer (score -1):

```
var rect = new CGRect(); 
rect.X = (nfloat)view.X; 
rect.Y = (nfloat)view.Y; 
rect.Width = (nfloat)view.Width; 
rect.Height = (nfloat)view.Height;
```

Solved it, where "view" is the Xamarin Forms view.